# recursion with pointer usage

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I'm dynamically allocating memory in main for a *two dimensional array*.For the sake of my project let's just say **i must** allocate memory in main and **must** pass the array in a *function1* and then pass the same array in a *function2* then call *function2* recursively.Any thoughts on how to do it without getting a segmentation fault?

main:

```
int main()
{
            int n,m;
            scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

            int **array;
            array = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
            if(array==NULL) printf("Couldn't allocate memory.\n");
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                array[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
                if(array[i]==NULL) printf("Couldn't allocate memory.\n");
            }

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
              for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
              {
                scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
              }
            }

            function1(n,m,array);

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
              free(array[i]);
            }
           free(array);
}
```

function1:

```
void function1(int n,int m,int **array)
{
   int S=0;
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
      S=function2(n-1,j,&array);
    }
}
```

function2:

```
int function2(int row,int column,int ***array) //it counts the sum of every column
{
    if(row==1) return (*array)[row][column];
    int number = (*array)[row][column];
    long middle = number + function2(row-1,column,array); //i get a Segmentation Fault
}
```

Comment: 1. Which programming language is this? 2. How are you allocating your `array`? Please provide a proper [mcve]

Comment: alright im going to edit the question hold on

Comment: This is in C language by the way.

Comment: Your `n` and `m` in `main` are not initialized and there is no definition of `i` or `j` in `function2`. Please make sure your example compiles and reproduces the issue

Comment: @UnholySheep you're right sorry!

Comment: The first time `function2` (which doesn't return anything, so it's UB) is called, `row` is equal to 0, so that the call `function2(row-1,column,array)` results in a access out of bounds. BTW, why are you passing a ***?

Comment: @Bob__ **row** is equal to n.Where did you see the 0? I'm passing the array with *** solely because when i passed the array with ** i would get a segmentation everytime i used the array for anything.Even when i wrote something simple as that:array[row][column]

Comment: I stand corrected, it would be an out of bounds access on the other side: you can't use `n` as a row index (in `int number = (*array)[row][column];`), which should be in range [0, n-1]. Please look at the generated assembly for `function1` (which has undefined behavior) and the warnings [here](https://godbolt.org/z/N_mnxW).

Comment: @Bob__ waaa you're right!! thanks for the notice!i'm going to edit it

Comment: @Bob__ the link you posted what kind of website is that?Is it something like a debugger?

Comment: Not really, see e.g. https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/wiki